# How to test a website to be used with Ipad in Windows 7

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ipad, cross-browser, mobile-safari

I'm an ASP.net developer and I need to test my website, mainly javascript and client side, in order to be cross browser capable. I did it in IE, FF, CH but I need to check whether this web site is rendered correctly in **Apple Ipads**. However I don't have and won't have Ipad.

How can I test it? Is there any "emulator" or similar right there?
thank you.

Comment: There's http://ipadpeek.com/ as a starting point but I'm sure there'll be better answers than that.

Comment: updated my answer a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest is to use dekstop Safari, but that will mostly help with layout and basic JavaScript. However, to actually get proper results you need to have an actual iPad. Quite some things don't work the same way (events, multimedia support and more).

For layout and basic JS testing you could try something like [Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc), Chrome extension that provides you with a wrapper to iFrame and some other little enhancements for testing in desktop browser.

You can also use a service like http://www.browserstack.com/ which provides you with real experience (of course touch events will still be "proxied" through mouse). Although it's a bit costy, but I think they have a free trial.

**UPD**. And there is another service a bit cheaper that offers the way to properly test – http://saucelabs.com/home

Answer (score 0):

IpadPeek will help, but there is no substitute for the real thing. If you can't buy one, can't you borrow one for a while or ask someone who does have one to test it for you? I can say from experience, iPadPeek will help, but its far from perfect and really isn't going to give you the piece of mind you need to say your website will work on the iPad.